# How to know if RAPI dll is existing

Tags: c#

I have build C# program that work with RAPI (communication to PPC or WinCE)

My problem is, if the user was not installed the ActiveSync - my program crashed !!

How can I load and work with my program without install ActiveSync ?

(maybe something like #if...#define..... i realy dont know.....)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices here:

One, delay load the RAPI dll so you're app won't complain if the DLL is not there. In this situation, you'd only use the RAPI calls if ActiveSync was installed (you can determine this by checking the registry).

-or-

Two, dynamically load the RAPI dll and only reference the RAPI functions if ActiveSync is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are thinking, but you put your code behind an interface and into another DLL, then when you program starts, look to see if RAPI can be found (look for the files or install code).

If it is found, load the DLL and get the interface to the code that uses it, if it is not found, the don't load the DLL and disable any UI options that need it.